# python one liner to split, perform operation, convert to the list

Tags: python

I want to split the string based on comma except if the comma is within '|'.
If the input is

```
str = '|ab,,c|,pqr,xyz'
```

then the output should be

```
['ab,,c', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

I have a code so far like this which generates array like this

```
['|ab,,c|', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

and I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in one line. I see `strip` function in python to remove first and last character of a string but not sure how to use it here

```
str.split(regex).tolist()
```

Comment: You can simply use `.strip('|')` with the result you have. I don't think there will be a simple way to do this in one line. Better to have a program with more than one line that works and is easy to understand.

Comment: true but how to use it in here str.split(regex).tolist()?

Comment: you can use list comprehension`[x.strip('|') for x in str.split(regex)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

s = '|ab,,c|,pqr,xyz'

print(next(csv.reader(StringIO(s), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')))
```

Prints:

```
['ab,,c', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just match the groups:

```
import re

instr = '|ab,,c|,pqr,xyz'    

grouper = re.compile(r'(\|[^|]+?\||[^,|]+)')
grouper.findall(instr)
```

Output:

```
['|ab,,c|', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

If you really want a one-liner:

```
re.findall(r'(\|[^|]+?\||[^,|]+)', instr)
```

Comment: not a downvoter OP asked for one liner solution and expected output is `['ab,,c', 'pqr', 'xyz']`

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind your task is reading a csv file with "|" replacing the standard quotationmarks. The following approach utilizes the csv library and uses the StringIO function to convert the string to an adquate format.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

str = '|ab,,c|,pqr,xyz'
f = StringIO(str)

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")

print(next(reader)) # you could also iterate over reader by using a for-loop but in this case your input only consists of one line
```

or written as a one liner:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

result = next(csv.reader(StringIO('|ab,,c|,pqr,xyz'), delimiter=",", quotechar="|"))
# yields ['ab,,c', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

Using regex in this case is not the right choice

Answer (score 0):

not the very pretty looking one, but does its job as asked in a one-liner:

```
print([e for i in [", ".join(x.split(',')) if 'x' in x else x 
    for x in (x.strip(',') for x in s.split('|') if x)] for e in i.split(', ')])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['ab,,c', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```